# Stretch Image to Fit 100% of Div Height and Width

Tags: html, css

I have a div with the following CSS

```
#mydiv{
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

and my HTML looks like this

```
<div id = "mydiv">
    <img src = "folder/file.jpg" width = "200px" height = "200px">
</div>
```

I'd like my web image to always be the same size (in a 1:1 aspect ration) no matter what the resolution of the actual image is.  If my actual image files are square (with 1:1 ratio) then this isn't a problem.  But if the actual image files are not square then the displayed web image do stretch to 100% of both the div's height and width (in this case 200px).

How do I get different image sizes to fit to my DIV?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're mixing notations. It should be:

```
<img src="folder/file.jpg" width="200" height="200">
```

(note, no *px*). Or:

```
<img src="folder/file.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
```

(using the *style* attribute) The style attribute could be replaced with the following CSS:

```
#mydiv img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

or

```
#mydiv img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of setting absolute widths and heights, you can use percentages:

```
#mydiv img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: And, if your image is right next down the DOM tree use the *direct child selector*, `#mydiv > img` - major performance optimization right there. Remember, browsers (and most libraries like jQuery too) read CSS from right to left.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can put in the CSS,

```
<style>
div#img {
  background-image: url(“file.png");
  color:yellow (this part doesn't matter;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

will the height attribute stretch the image beyond its native resolution? If I have a image with a height of say 420 pixels, I can't get css to stretch the image beyond the native resolution to fill the height of the viewport.

I am getting pretty close results with:

```
 .rightdiv img {
        max-width: 25vw;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
```

the 100vh is getting pretty close, with just a few pixels left over at the bottom for some reason.