# CSS : width:100% or fixed height whichever is smaller

Tags: css, height, width

i want to make the `img` fit the `div` height if it is smaller than the width or fit the `div` width if it is smaller than the height i want this to work well even when the `img` is small i want it to stretch to fit the max-height of the div or stretch to fit the 100% width of the div without losing the aspect ratio
this is where i am so far https://jsfiddle.net/okbor1n2/

```css
div{
  max-height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
img{
margin:auto;
display:block;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/73/24/05/7324050b8a2c7f22e1134d08bbc8e6e1--entrance-table-entry-tables.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: May the image be a `background-image` ?

Comment: Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501668/stretch-image-to-fit-100-of-div-height-and-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501668/stretch-image-to-fit-100-of-div-height-and-width)

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for [Force an image to fit and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34713763/483779)

Comment: @Brainfeeder no i can't use a background-image it must be an `img` tag also the link you mentioned doesn't have an answer to my question

Comment: @Stickers thank you very much i found the answer using `object-fit: contain;` did just what i wanted thanks for directing me to that link

Comment: @mennayoussef Do the images get uploaded with a CMS? You’ll have to crop all the images to same size on upload then? Don’t know about a css solution for this... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It worked for me.

```
<div>
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/73/24/05/7324050b8a2c7f22e1134d08bbc8e6e1--entrance-table-entry-tables.jpg">
</div>
<style>
    div{
        max-height:200px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    img{
       width: 100%;
       margin:auto;
       display:block;
       padding-top: 0%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: it didn't work for me it just clips the extra height from the img